# What's the honorific to represent a female's older sister?

Tags: honorific, polite, speech-levels

I got to know that Korean grammar uses an extensive system of `honorifics` and those are used to differentiate between formal and informal speech.

So ways to formal speech is to honorific nouns and verbs.I was searching for these and found a [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_honorifics#Honorific_nouns) which give some examples on how to use but I'm unable to find out :

- How to formally call 언니 (**`female's older sister`**) ? Can we use **`eonnim`** or (**`eonninim`**) ?
- Why the honorific for 오빠 (**`oppa`**) became 오라버니 (**`orabeoni`**) instead of `oppani` or `oppanim` ?

For the first one  it has already `ni` suffix in `eonni` and that's why I guess there is no honorific, if this is the case how do call `eonni` informally or as a person who is on the same level/same social status.

Comment: I believe this would be 누이, but I'm not 100% sure so I'll just leave it in a comment for now.

Comment: @dotVezz When a man indicates his (younger) sister, he uses 누이. See [here](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=8014600).

Comment: @choco_addicted yeah I saw that too, which is kind of confusing because if you look [here](http://krdic.naver.com/search.nhn?query=%EC%96%B8%EB%8B%88&kind=all) it seems to say that 누이 **is** the 유의어 for 언니. So idrk, it's sort of contradictory but I think you're right - there does't really seem to be an equivalent of 오라버니 for 언니

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"오라버니" has a long history in its etymology and actually it comes from Chinese characters, 오(吾)-압(亞)-아(御)-이(爾).

압(亞)-아(御)-이(爾) (it became 아버지, 어버이) means a 'father' and 오(吾) means a 'brother'. It literally translates to "brother father". In old days in Korea, when a father died, the eldest brother acted as a father of a family.

It has nothing to do with '오빠' etymologically, but became an honorific noun for it. You can never use '오빠니' as it doesn't make any sense. '오빠님' could be used for a joke, but nobody uses it to mean '오라버니'.

There is no honorific noun for '언니' because there was no counterpart of 오(吾)-압(亞)-아(御)-이(爾) in the past. You should not use "언니님" unless you are making a joke.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be no honorific expression of 언니.

> {언니}는 여성끼리의 호칭어다. 앞서 확인한 다른 호칭어와 같이 친족 집단에서 사용되며 비 친족 집단에서 [친밀]의 공유를 중심으로 사용되는 공통점을 가진다. 하지만 다른 어휘소가 {형님}, {오라버니}, {누님}같은 확장 어휘소를 가지는 것과 달리 {언니}는 별도의 확장 어휘소가 없으며 [높임]을 표현할 때는 (3 "6")처럼 {형님}을 사용한다.<sup>1</sup>

Here (3 "6") is the sixth meaning of "[형님](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=42514600)".

### Reference

1. 김광순 (2015). 친족어의 호칭어로서 확장ㆍ사용 양상. 한국어의미학, 48, 175-201.